# Why is my Alert component triggering multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, expo

This is my React Native code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert, View, Image, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing, TouchableOpacity, Text, ScrollView, ImageBackground, Dimensions, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import * as Brightness from 'expo-brightness';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //styles
});

const DisplayLogo = () => {
  const [showSeparatePage, setShowSeparatePage] = useState(false);
  const [showWeatherPage, setShowWeatherPage] = useState(false);
  const [showBuyImplementsPage, setShowBuyImplementsPage] = useState(false);
  const [showSellHarvestPage, setShowSellHarvestPage] = useState(false);
  const [showAudioPodcastsPage, setShowAudioPodcastsPage] = useState(false);
  const [showDonatePage, setShowDonatePage] = useState(false);
  const [showFeedbackPage, setShowFeedbackPage] = useState(false);
  const [showBackButton, setShowBackButton] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [contact, setContact] = useState(false);
  const [settingsMenu, setSettingsMenu] = useState(false);
  const translateY = new Animated.Value(700);
  const logoOpacity = new Animated.Value(1);
  const buttonOpacity = new Animated.Value(0);
  const backgroundColor = new Animated.Value(0);
  const showHelpDialog = () => {
    setModalVisible(true);
  };
  const hideHelpDialog = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    handleBackButtonPress();
  };
  const showContactDialog = () => {
    setContact(true);
  };
  const hideContactDialog = () => {
    setContact(false);
    handleBackButtonPress();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const logoAnimation = Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(translateY, {
        toValue: 250,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
      }),
      Animated.delay(2000),
      Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(translateY, {
          toValue: -50,
          duration: 1000,
          useNativeDriver: true,
          easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
        }),
        Animated.timing(logoOpacity, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1000,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]),
    ]);

    const buttonsAnimation = Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      delay: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    });

    Animated.sequence([logoAnimation, buttonsAnimation]).start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      translateY.setValue(500);
      logoOpacity.setValue(1);
      buttonOpacity.setValue(0);
      backgroundColor.setValue(0);
    };
  }, [showSeparatePage, showWeatherPage, showBuyImplementsPage, showSellHarvestPage, showAudioPodcastsPage, showDonatePage, showFeedbackPage, modalVisible, settingsMenu, contact]);

  const handleTipsForFarmingPress = () => {
    setShowSeparatePage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleWeatherReportPress = () => {
    setShowWeatherPage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleBuyImplementsPress = () => {
    setShowBuyImplementsPage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleSellHarvestPress = () => {
    setShowSellHarvestPage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleAudioPodcastsPress = () => {
    setShowAudioPodcastsPage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleDonatePress = () => {
    setShowDonatePage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleFeedbackPress = () => {
    setShowFeedbackPage(true);
    setShowBackButton(true);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 2,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const handleBackButtonPress = () => {
    setShowSeparatePage(false);
    setShowWeatherPage(false);
    setShowBuyImplementsPage(false);
    setShowSellHarvestPage(false);
    setShowAudioPodcastsPage(false);
    setShowDonatePage(false);
    setShowFeedbackPage(false);
    setModalVisible(false);
    setContact(false);
    setSettingsMenu(false);
    setShowBackButton(false);
    Animated.timing(buttonOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  if (showSeparatePage) {
    return (
      //returns something
    );
  }
  if (showWeatherPage) {
    return (
      //returns something
    );
  }
  if (showBuyImplementsPage) {
    return (
        //returns something
    );
  }
  if (showSellHarvestPage) {
    return (
        //returns something
    );
  }
  if (showAudioPodcastsPage) {
    return (
        <//returns something
    );
  }
  if (showDonatePage) {
    return (
        //returns something
    );
  }
  if (showFeedbackPage) {
    return (
        //returns something
    );
  }
  if (modalVisible) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Help',
      "Click buttons and navigate throughout the platform.",
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
          hideHelpDialog();
          handleBackButtonPress();
        }}
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }
  //The bug occurs in the below Alert component.
  if (settingsMenu) {
    console.log("Alert");
      Alert.alert("Settings","Set brightness.",
      [
        {text:"High Brightness", onPress: () => {
          Brightness.setBrightnessAsync(1);
          handleBackButtonPress();
        }},
        {text:"Medium Brightness", onPress: () => {
          Brightness.setBrightnessAsync(0.4);
          handleBackButtonPress();
        }},
        {text:"Low Brightness", onPress: () => {
          Brightness.setBrightnessAsync(0.2);
          handleBackButtonPress();
        }}
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }
  if (contact) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Contact',
      "Call Centre Number: 1234567890",
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
          hideContactDialog();
          handleBackButtonPress();
        }}
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Animated.View style={{ ...styles.container, backgroundColor: backgroundColor.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
        outputRange: ['white', 'skyblue', 'orange'],
      }) }}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            ...styles.logo,
            transform: [{ translateY }],
            opacity: logoOpacity,
          }}
          source={require('./assets/Logo.png')}
        />

        <Animated.View style={{ ...styles.buttonContainer, opacity: buttonOpacity }}>
          {/* Yellow buttons */}
          {['Tips For Farming', 'Weather Updates', 'Buy Implements', 'Sell Harvest', 'Audio Podcasts', 'Donate'].map(
            (buttonName, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                style={{ ...styles.button, ...styles.yellowButton }}
                onPress={() => {
                  if (buttonName==='Tips For Farming') {
                    handleTipsForFarmingPress()}
                  if (buttonName==='Weather Updates') {
                    handleWeatherReportPress()}
                  if (buttonName==='Buy Implements') {
                    handleBuyImplementsPress()}
                  if (buttonName==='Sell Harvest') {
                    handleSellHarvestPress()}
                  if (buttonName==='Audio Podcasts') {
                    handleAudioPodcastsPress()}
                  if (buttonName==='Donate') {
                    handleDonatePress()}
                  }
                }
              >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{buttonName}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          )}

          {/* Gray buttons */}
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            {['Help', 'Settings'].map((buttonName, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                style={{ ...styles.button, ...styles.grayButton, marginLeft: 10 }}
                onPress={() => {
                  if (buttonName==='Help') {
                    showHelpDialog();}
                  if (buttonName==='Settings') {
                    setSettingsMenu(true);}
                }
              }
              >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{buttonName}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </View>

          {/* Orange button */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ ...styles.button, ...styles.orangeButton }}
            onPress={() => handleFeedbackPress()}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Return Feedback</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          {/* Green button */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ ...styles.button, ...styles.greenButton }}
            onPress={() => showContactDialog()}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Contact</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      </Animated.View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default DisplayLogo;
```

Basically, when the Settings button is clicked, a dialog box appears. When I choose an option, the dialog box reappears, sometimes twice or thrice.

This bug is not occurring with the other Alert components. Also, when a dialog box appears, the logo of my app animates in the background (which should only happen when the app starts). I don't want the Alert component to trigger continuously. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `alert()` method within an event handler not state change. An element is rendered due to any state change and if the state that triggers the method call is true it will be executed multiple times. Something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
...
  onPress={() => {
    if (buttonName === 'Help') {
      Alert.alert(...);
    }
    if (buttonName === 'Settings') {
      Alert.alert(...);
    }
  }}>
  ...
</TouchableOpacity>;
```